# Authorization callback URL for Screwdriver.cd

Tags: github, screwdriver-cd

I am trying to spin up my own instance of Screwdriver.cd and to generate oauthClientId and oauthClientSecret I need Authorization callback URL. Can someone please help me with the Authorization callback URL and homepage URL for screwdriver.cd

I am trying to register a new OAuth application with below values:
[Register a new OAuth application values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOoTc.png)

presuming the Homepage URL would be `https://screwdriver.cd/`, please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [SD-in-a-box](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/in-a-box#screwdriver-in-a-box) to spin up your own instance, there should be text telling you what to put for Homepage URL and Authorization callback URL, like in this example: https://docs.screwdriver.cd/cluster-management/running-locally.

But basically, Homepage URL should be your *local UI URL* (for example, `http://localhost:9000`). Authorization callback URL should point to your *local API with `/v4/auth/login` appended to the end* (for example, `http://localhost:9001/v4/auth/login`).

Comment: I am looking to spin up an instance of Screwdriver.cd on AWS EKS cluster, will the local configs still hold for Authorization callback URL and homepage URL?

Comment: @TannuPriya If you're using [Helm chart](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver-chart), you'll need to use whatever API and UI uri's you set in your `values.yaml` file: https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver-chart/blob/master/values.yaml#L34-L35